# Google Analytics Audiences Not Synching with Google Ads Correctly.

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, gwt, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have audiences synced between google analytics and google ad words. There is a huge discrepancy between the two (see Below) and I have no idea why. I used google tag manager to implement my code and it seems to be set up correctly.

Some insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!
[GA Audience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p3z3.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can also ask GWT questions from GWT developers here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt